# JSON data parsing in android

Tags: android, json

I am having trouble in parsing JSON. I have a string as such,

```
String result = "[{"id":"1","brand_name":"Unilever","brand_image":"collaboration_2.jpg","brand_description":"Unilever is the world's leading company and blah blah ","is_active":"1"},{"id":"2","brand_name":"Engro","brand_image":"people-icon-in-vector-format14.jpg","brand_description":"Engro is another brand and blah blah blah blah\r\n","is_active":"1"}]";
```

and here is trying code i am trying but getting null pointer exception

```
String brands[] = null;

JSONArray data = new JSONArray(result);

for(int j=0; j<data.length();j++){
    brands[j] = data.getJSONObject(j).getString("brand_name");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Java guy .It seems to me that you should initialize the 
brands[] variable before using it.

Also check for variable data for null & data.getJSONObject(j) before calling the method.

Comment: You are correct. I suggest the OP use `ArrayList<String>` with the `add()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to look into GSON. It really makes working with json easy. Heres link: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

I once tried parsing a JSON String returned by my web service. Here is what I did:

The response I got from the web service was:

> {"checkrecord":[{"rollno":"abc2","percentage":40,"attended":12,"missed":34}],"Table1":[]}

In order to parse I did the following:

```
  JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
  JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("checkrecord"); 
  int max = array.length();

 for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) 
 {
  JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
  JSONArray names = obj.names();


 for (int k = 0; k < names.length(); k++) 
 {
  String name = names.getString(k);
  String value= obj.getString(name);  

 }

}
```

My JSONObject looks like this:

> {"Table1":[],"checkrecord":[{"missed":34,"attended":12,"percentage":40,"rollno":"abc2"}]}

You need to do modifications as per your code and requirements.

Hope it helps

Cheers